# Colab TPU error - InvalidArgumentError: Unsupported data type for TPU: double, caused by output cond_8/Merge:0

Tags: machine-learning, google-colaboratory, google-cloud-tpu, tpu

I'm trying to do some basic character classification on google colab with a TPU. I'm getting the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Unsupported data type for TPU: double, caused by output cond_8/Merge:0
```

I don't know what the issue is since I'm using float32 when creating numpy arrays.  I also don't know what cond_8/Merge:0 refers to.  The input file I load is a JSON array that represents a lot of 28x28 grayscale images

```
[{"label":25,"data":[[[1],[.56720000]...],...]}]
```

I have tried commenting out all the layers except the first input layer and the problem still occurs!! My code is:

```
import os, re, math, json, shutil, pprint
import PIL.Image, PIL.ImageFont, PIL.ImageDraw
import numpy as np
import json
import tensorflow as tf
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.python.platform import tf_logging
from google.colab import drive
print("Tensorflow version " + tf.__version__)

with open('/tmp/encoded.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

print("Got data")

images_data = list(map(lambda row: row["data"],data))
label_data = list(map(lambda row: row["label"],data))

print("mapped data")

images_data_tensor = np.asarray(images_data, dtype=np.float32)
label_data_tensor = np.asarray(label_data, dtype=np.float32)

print("converted to tensors")

BATCH_SIZE = 128


N = 24


# This model trains to 99.4% sometimes 99.5% accuracy in 10 epochs (with a batch size of 32)
def create_model():
  l = tf.keras.layers
  model = tf.keras.Sequential(
    [
      #l.Reshape(input_shape=(28*28,), target_shape=(28, 28, 1)),

      l.Conv2D(input_shape=(28,28,1,), filters=6, kernel_size=3, padding='same', use_bias=False), # no bias necessary before batch norm
      l.BatchNormalization(scale=False, center=True), # no batch norm scaling necessary before "relu"
      l.Activation('relu'), # activation after batch norm

      l.Conv2D(filters=12, kernel_size=6, padding='same', use_bias=False, strides=2),
      l.BatchNormalization(scale=False, center=True),
      l.Activation('relu'),

      l.Conv2D(filters=24, kernel_size=6, padding='same', use_bias=False, strides=2),
      l.BatchNormalization(scale=False, center=True),
      l.Activation('relu'),

      l.Flatten(),
      l.Dense(200, use_bias=False),
      l.BatchNormalization(scale=False, center=True),
      l.Activation('relu'),
      l.Dropout(0.5), # Dropout on dense layer only

      l.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
    ])
  return model

# set up learning rate decay
lr_decay = tf.keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler(lambda epoch: 0.0001 + 0.02 * math.pow(0.5, 1+epoch), verbose=True)


EPOCHS = 10
tpu = None

# Default strategy for GPU/CPU. Note that tensorflow-gpu will need to be installed for GPU to work
strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()

try: # TPU detection
  tpu = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver() # Picks up a connected TPU on Google's Colab, ML Engine, Kubernetes and Deep Learning VMs accessed through the 'ctpu up' utility
  #tpu = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver('MY_TPU_NAME') # If auto-detection does not work, you can pass the name of the TPU explicitly (tip: on a VM created with "ctpu up" the TPU has the same name as the VM)
  tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(tpu)
  strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.TPUStrategy(tpu)
except ValueError:
  print('Training on CPU')

with strategy.scope():
  trained_model = create_model()
  trained_model.compile(optimizer='adam', # learning rate will be set by LearningRateScheduler
                loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                metrics=['accuracy'])

  # print model layers
  trained_model.summary()

  history = trained_model.fit(x=images_data_tensor,y=label_data_tensor, epochs=EPOCHS, callbacks=[lr_decay])  


print(history.history.keys())
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I am having the same error.

Comment: @chiragzq Sadly, no

Answer (score 0):

I also meet this error in google colab tpu when I used keras-bert for run classify.
I turn down the batch size and maxlength ,then the error gone and I do not know why. So you can try to turn down your batch size in the model.

Comment: Can you clarify and add more details? Maybe a Step by Step or Bulletpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Met this error on kaggle.  In my case problem was datatype of target was string converting it to numeric datatype solved it.  Hope it helps.

Comment: Converting string target to numeric solved my problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a call `tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(tpu)`

Please try running it with Tensorflow 2.1+ and having TPU initialization/detection at the beginning.

```
# detect and init the TPU
tpu = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver()
tf.config.experimental_connect_to_cluster(tpu)
tf.tpu.experimental.initialize_tpu_system(tpu)

# instantiate a distribution strategy
tpu_strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.TPUStrategy(tpu)
```